# Openshift change time server

Tags: openshift

I have a JAVA application on Jboss Aplication Server, and it is on America zone.
It is a web-app just in case.

The time that i see on logs is America timer, but i would like to change server time for my local zone. So i can have my application in American zone, like it is now, but see time for my localzone. So i litteraly would like to change the server timezone, just that.

Should i change that in some openshift variable, or something?
It is possible? If yes, how i can do that??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the server time zone. However, you should be able to change the time zone for the app server. Provided you were talking about the app server logs, it should also to the trick. You should be able to add something like this to your pre start action hook:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Stockholm"
```

(or whatever the timezone is you want to use).

Answer (score -1):

Use JAVA_OPTS_EXT instead. Remember to put trailing and leading spaces, like:

```
export JAVA_OPTS_EXT=" -Duser.timezone=America/Regina "
```

Add this in 'pre_start' file in action_hooks folder, push it and restart the server. JBoss Application server will run in the specified time-zone.

Comment: I added the file in /var/lib/openshift/user/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks, but didnt change time. Also i didnt see my variable on logs with others JAVA_OPTS_EXT. Althought, the file dissapeared when i pushed something to server and it reboot, so i guess it readed